# GDB: can't read symbols: File format not recognized

Tags: gdb, cross-compiling, unreal-engine4, arm64

I cross-compiled an empty [unreal](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/SharingAndReleasing/Linux/GettingStarted/)(engine version 4.25) game with the clang([v16 clang-9.0.1-based](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/SharingAndReleasing/Linux/GettingStarted/)), and generated the symbol file `UE4Game-LinuxAArch64-Debug.sym`.
When I ran the game on a development board, it crashed with core dumps, all the symbols displayed well.

But when I debug it with gdb (7.12.1) and load symbols with:

```sh
symbol-file UE4Game-LinuxAArch64-Debug.sym
```

It failed with

```
can't read symbols: File format not recognized.
```

Comment: What does "all the symbols displayed well" mean? What does your `gdb --version` say? Where do you run that GDB?

Comment: I run gdb on then board, `gdb --version` shows `GNU gdb (GDB) 7.12.1`. I can see the core dump with symbols when running the game directly, but in GDB there's no symbol infomations but only function address.

Answer (score 2):

As I found the .sym file is not the debug symbol file in unreal. There's another .debug file. .sym file used for unreal to print log with symbols not for GDB.